# Using result of one query into the next query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have successfully executed one query which gives me the average of one of the particular field in my schema. I want to use the value of average I got in previous query in the next query to compare. When I am trying to do it, the command prompt is considering it as two different queries rather than one.

How can I do it in MongoDB?

Comment: Can you show us your current queries?

Comment: First Query:   var reduceFunction = function(currentValue, previousValue) {
    previousValue.total += currentValue.stars;
 previousValue.count += 1;
};
var finalizeFunction = function(currentValue) {
    currentValue.average = currentValue.total/currentValue.count; 
};
Result =  db.business.group({
   "_id": {"stars": true },
    initial: {total: 0, count:0},
    reduce: reduceFunction,
    finalize: finalizeFunction
});

Comment: Second Query: db.business.find({stars: {$gt : Result.average}})

Comment: This seems more like an "API" question rather than for a shell operation, so it would help if you defined this in terms of the language you are actually using. Also better to give a sample of doccuments and expected result, as I suspect `.aggregate()` would acutally suit you better. Finally there is an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32961080/edit) link on your question that allows you to add details rather than post in comments. Welcom to StackOverflow. You will get better responses from a more detailed and clear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are really asking in context of the API you are using rather than processing in the shell, but the principles remain the same.

Your first result is always an "array" as returned by the `.group()` method, therefore to access that as a singular value you need to only return the "first" array element, which is the `0` index.

Also your operation and whole case is merely looking for the  "average value" of a field and then looking to query for those items that are greater than that returned average value. The [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method has a much simplier syntax for this as well as running much faster since it's operations are all natively coded and not JavaScript interpreted, which in the latter case would slow things down significantly.

Use native operations unless there is no alternative:

```js
var result  = db.business.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "average": { "$avg": "$stars" }
    }}
]).toArray()[0];

db.business.find({ "stars": { "$gt": result.average } })
```

The first operation reduces down to an array of a single object, from which you take just that first item from the array. Then the object can just be referenced in your second query, returning the result.

In an async environment, you just need to call the second query within the callback result of the first operation in order to see the scoped result once that operation is complete. But use `.aggregate()` since it is better suited to the task, and faster.